# Is this really a bug in the JAVASCRIPT or am i doing something wrong with the Date, datatype

Tags: javascript, date

```js
let d = new Date('2018,7,26');

let c = new Date()
c.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)
document.write(c);
document.write("<br>");

c.setDate(d.getDate() + 5)
document.write(c);
document.write("<br>");

c.setDate(d.getDate() + 6)
document.write(c);
document.write("<br>");

c.setDate(d.getDate() + 7)
document.write(c);
document.write("<br>");

c.setDate(d.getDate() + 8)
document.write(c);
document.write("<br>");

c.setDate(d.getDate() + 9)
document.write(c);
document.write("<br>");

c.setDate(d.getDate() + 10)
document.write(c);
document.write("<br>");
```

The output of running this code:

```
Fri Jul 27 2018 14:35:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Tue Jul 31 2018 14:35:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Wed Aug 01 2018 14:35:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Sun Sep 02 2018 14:35:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Thu Oct 04 2018 14:35:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Sun Nov 04 2018 14:35:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Thu Dec 06 2018 14:35:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

This looks like a bug. If today is 2018-07-26 (i.e. July, 26), then adding 7 days to it should be 2018-08-02 (August, 2nd). But, it is September, 2nd. Then, adding further makes it even worse.

What is the way around this issue? How to increment dates properly in `JS`?

Comment: Your results are correct.

Comment: In my browser, `d` is invalid to begin with, and every subsequent operation results in "`Invalid Date`"… This is simply not something that is supposed to work.

Comment: No you are doing it wrong. When you are setting the date and giving input like 32 , 34 . it tries to give the same response. So use the date from original

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [stated on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate)

> If the dayValue is outside of the range of date values for the month,
>   setDate() will update the Date object accordingly. For example, if 0
>   is provided for dayValue, the date will be set to the last day of the
>   previous month.

If a month has 31 days and you will set the day to 33, it will go to the next month + 2, so August 2nd in this case.

The problem here is that if you again add 34 days, it will stay on the month it incremented to at the previous `setDate()` and again add one month + the days it has more than that month has. (august has 31 days, so it will set to the 3th).

So to take your example:

```
// let d = new Date('2018,7,26');
// d.getDate will always return 26

let c = new Date();
c.setDate(27); // works fine, month has 31 days
c.setDate(31); // same
c.setDate(32); // will go to next month + 1, so august 1st
c.setDate(33); // we're at august, august has 31 days so august + 1 month + 2 days = september 2nd
c.setDate(34); // september has 30 days goes to October + 4 days = October 4th
```

To properly keep adding days you can clone the date:

```js
let d = new Date('2018-07-26');

let c = new Date()
let e;

e = new Date(c.getTime())
e.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
console.log(e);

e = new Date(c.getTime())
e.setDate(d.getDate() + 5);
console.log(e);

e = new Date(c.getTime())
e.setDate(d.getDate() + 6);
console.log(e);

e = new Date(c.getTime())
e.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
console.log(e);

e = new Date(c.getTime())
e.setDate(d.getDate() + 8);
console.log(e);

e = new Date(c.getTime())
e.setDate(d.getDate() + 9);
console.log(e);

e = new Date(c.getTime())
e.setDate(d.getDate() + 10);
console.log(e);
```

Also do note as [Deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) mentioned in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51535087/is-this-really-a-bug-in-the-javascript-or-am-i-doing-something-wrong-with-the-da/51535763#comment90038163_51535087), the date format you used in for creating the date does not work for every browser. Rather use something like `2018-07-26`.

Answer (score 4):

When you set `c` to something more then the number of days in the month it increases the month in the `c`. The problem with your code is that you do not clear value of `c` and it keeps increasing current month in `c` with each `setDate` that has argument > `31`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no bug in JS. It's just that you misunderstood how your code works. Pay attention to this code.

```
c.setDate(d.getDate() + 6) // this will set the c date into 2018-08-01
document.write(c);
document.write("<br>");

c.setDate(d.getDate() + 7)
document.write(c);
document.write("<br>");
```

`d.getDate() + 7` should give you the result `2018-08-02`. However, you put it into `c` variable which the month is set to 8 due to previous setting. Thus, the month gets increment again and the result is `2018-09-02` and it applies to the rest of code.

This is the fixed code to get your desired result.

```
var arr = [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; // you can edit this line according to your needs
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let c = new Date();
    c.setDate(d.getDate() + arr[i]);
    document.write(c);
    document.write("<br>");
}
```